# How do I retain a value through multiple levels of recursion?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I have written a quick sort program which counts the number of swaps performed to sort an array in ascending order. In this program , I have used a global variable to count the number of swaps as I was not able figure how to retain values through multiple levels of recursion. I understand the concept that the value is to be retained by passing through multiple levels of recursion when the function is folding itself but I am clearly unable to implement it. Can someone please suggest me the way to do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickSort {

    // global variable for counting the quicksort shifts.
    private static int swapCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // scanning the values;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scan.nextInt();
        int ar[] = new int[N];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){
            int value = scan.nextInt();
            ar[i] = value;
        }

        quickSort(ar, 0, ar.length-1);
        System.out.println(swapCount);

    }

    //quickSort
    public static void quickSort(int ar[], int start, int end){

        if(start<end){
            int pIndex = partition(ar, start, end);
            quickSort(ar,start, pIndex-1);
            quickSort(ar, pIndex+1, end);   
        }
    } 

    // partition function
    public static int partition(int ar[], int start, int end){
        int pivot = ar[end];
        int pIndex = start;
        for (int i = start ; i < end ; i++ ){
            if(ar[i] < pivot){
                int temp = ar[i];  
                ar[i] = ar[pIndex];
                ar[pIndex] = temp;
                swapCount++;
                pIndex++;
            }
        }
        int temp = ar[end];
        ar[end] = ar[pIndex];
        ar[pIndex] = temp;
        swapCount++;
        return pIndex;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You can pass an object that contains the value down the call stack. This could be an ad hoc class, or simply an `int[]`.

Comment: This is one case where a static (global) variable may make sense. It allows you to profile code without changing the interface (the call parameters). You can easily remove it after your testing is done. As commented, if you do want to pass the static variable as a parameter, you have to pass it by reference, which Java does not support for primitive types, so as answered below, you have to create a class / object in order to pass by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that in Java values of primitive types like int when passed into functions do not reflect any changes made to them inside the function if you look at their value after the function returns.  The way to get around that issue, even though it isn't necessarily "good style", is to pass a Class object into the function instead of a primitive object, and then changes to the class object's member variables made inside the function will be reflected outside later.

```
// in main()
Integer nbrSwaps = new Interger(0);
quickSort(ar, 0, ar.length-1, nbrSwaps);

//quickSort
public static void quickSort(int ar[], int start, int end, Integer swapCount) {

  if(start<end){
    int pIndex = partition(ar, start, end, swapCount);
    quickSort(ar,start, pIndex-1, swapCount);
    quickSort(ar, pIndex+1, end, swapCount);   
  }
}

// partition function
public static int partition(int ar[], int start, int end, Integer swapCount) {
  ... as before ...
}
```